# How to format RAID hard drive

Tags: lvm, fdisk

I need to format(empty hdd) a RAID 0 HDD which is as follow:

```
sdb 8:16 0 3.7T 0 disk
└─md126 9:126 0 3.7T 0 raid0 
  └─md126p3 259:2 0 3.7T 0 part
     ├─rootvg01-swap 253:0 0 4G 0 lvm
     ├─rootvg01-lv05 253:1 0 3.6T 0 lvm
     ├─rootvg01-lv04 253:2 0 29.3G 0 lvm
     ├─rootvg01-lv03 253:3 0 19.5G 0 lvm
     ├─rootvg01-lv02 253:4 0 19.5G 0 lvm
     └─rootvg01-lv01 253:5 0 19.5G 0 lvm
```

I tried to delete/remove those partitions in Ubuntu's Disk but can't delete.

How to format it in Ubuntu 20?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the RAID0 array does not include any other disks? See `sudo cat /proc/mdstat` to find out all disks included in the `md126` array if you are unsure.

You have an active LVM volume group named `rootvg01` on top of a partitioned RAID 0 array `md126`, on a whole unpartitioned disk `sdb`.

I'm assuming this is not your active root filesystem, but a disk from some other system you'll need to recycle to some other use. If you are trying to empty the disk your OS is currently running on, you should boot from a live media to guarantee good results.

Assuming that all the LVs are already unmounted and the `rootvg01-swap` LV is not in use as a swap area (check with `sudo swapon -s` if unsure; disable with `sudo swapoff /dev/rootvg01/swap` if necessary) the first thing you'll need to do is deactivate the volume group:

```
sudo vgchange -an rootvg01
```

If this causes an error message, stop and investigate before trying to go further.

After that, the RAID array should no longer be in use, and you can stop it:

```
sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md126
```

Once the RAID0 array is stopped, you can delete the RAID superblock:

```
sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdb
```

Just to be sure, wipe any remains of partition tables too:

```
sudo wipefs -a /dev/sdb
```

Now the disk should be effectively empty and unpartitioned. However, if you need to ensure any old data is unrecoverable (without a massive effort at least), you should at least write the disk full of zeroes (e.g. `sudo cat /dev/zero > /dev/sdb`). For a 3.7T disk, this is going to take a while, so you may want to skip this step if you don't need it.